# Javascript Regex OR doubts

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to clarify two doubts about javascript Regexs.

1. Is it possible to nest a second OR expression inside a primary one, as below **`(v|b|c)`**:

   ```
   /(value1|value2|value3|(v|b|c)alue4)/
   ```
2. Is it possible to break lines  into the same expression, as below (in order to be more readable):

   ```
   /(value1|
     value2|
     value3|
     (v|b|c)alue4)
   /
   ```

Thanks so much

Comment: For part1, have you tried it out? `/(value1|value2|value3|(v|b|c)alue4)/.test("balue4")`

Comment: 1) yes you can 2) no you cannot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you try it yourself?

#### Example 1

```
/(value1|value2|value3|(v|b|c)alue4)/.test("calue4")
```

```
-> true
```

#### Example 2

```js
/(value1|
  value2|
  value3|
  (v|b|c)alue4)
/.test("calue4")
```

```
->  Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /
```

---

If you really want to use that multi-line style, you can always use string concatenation and the `RegExp` object:

```
new RegExp("(value1|" +
           "value2|" +
           "value3|" +
           "(v|b|c)alue4)").test("calue4")
```

```
-> true
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on James answer; you can also escape newlines in a string instead of concatenating several strings.

```
new RegExp("(value1|\
value2|\
value3|\
(v|b|c)alue4)").test("calue4")
```

Does it make it more readable and should you do this? **No**

*Warning, this will incorporate white-space between `\` and the start of the next character.*

Comment: Wait, there's something wrong with this, it logs `false`

Comment: Ah, the preceding whitespace was incorporated in the line since we escaped the newline.